# Как нажать на кнопку вы текстовом браузере?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Перепробовал все текстовые браузеры на ubuntu, нужно на сайте нажать на кнопку "*Проверить логин*", но я нажимаю **enter** и ничего не происходит
Сайт callbot.site/prvonax/bot.php#
(Не реклама)

Comment: насколько мне известно, javascript не поддерживается ни одним текстовым http-клиентом.

Comment: То есть вообще никак?

Comment: links2 вроде поддерживает javascript

Comment: По-прежнему ничего не происходит

Comment: Нажимайте с помощью JS движка. Вам для каких целей? Хотя хорошие сайты обычно API для скриптов предоставляют.